# QuickFix/N reset

Tags: c#, quickfix

When I log on with this cgf I see QuickFix send 34=1 at the start of
the day - why is it forcing this reset of the seq?

```
# default settings for sessions
[DEFAULT]
FileStorePath=D:\Production\LOGS\storeFssOrdersUAT
FileLogPath=D:\Production\LOGS\logFssOrdersUAT
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=30
SenderCompID=TR

# session definition
[SESSION]
# inherit FileStorePath, FileLogPath, ConnectionType,
ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=FSS
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=910
SocketConnectHost=74.114
DataDictionary=D:\Production\FIX\FSS_FIX44.xml
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnDisconnect=N
ResetOnLogout=N
ResetSeqNumFlag=N
EncryptMethod=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this:

```
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
```

You have a daily session that resets seq at midnight.

Do you want a weeklong session?  Set `StartDay`/`EndDay`.